# What is the alternative for catch hook in microsoft FLOW

Tags: webhooks, zapier, power-automate

I know this question is bit ambiguous. Let me clear that up. First thing is, this question is about integrating two services using an integration service(Zapier, Flow or IFTTT.. But um focusing on ms flows in here). I need to connect one of my services via a wehbook URL given by ms flows so that i can send my request to flow.

So in Zapier we have something called `Webhooks by Zapier`  which gives us a public URL `catch hook` to trigger a particular zap. But in flows we dont have such thing. I was wondering whether we have an alternative in ms flows to fire a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

The thing is, i did not find a way to setup exact catch hook from ms flows. But there is an alternative. In ms flows they provides us a connector called `request` which generates a `post url`. This url is continuously listening just like catch hooks in zapier. 
.
One drawback of this alternative is, we have to manually setup the payload of the incoming request in order to use data in actions in `JSon schema`   format which is a headache.